# New environment, orphan line

Tags: macros, environments, widows-orphans

I created three environments for my document: a booklet for a treasure hunt with `scrreprt`.

I created 3 environments (the document is in french):

enigma:

```
\newenvironment{enigme}{\refstepcounter{enigme}\vspace{0.5cm}{\bfseries Énigme \theenigme\ : \\}}{\par\vspace{0.5cm}}
```

route indications:

```
\newenvironment{path}{\vspace{0.5cm}{\bfseries \textcolor{DarkBlue}{Parcours :} \\}}{\par\vspace{0.5cm}}
```

cultural indication:

```
\newcommand{\culture}[1]{\emph{#1.}}
```

It works perfectly, but the problem is that sometimes, the words "Énigme" or "Parcours", or the title of my cultural indication are orphan at the end of the page.

What could I do to avoid this? Could I add a test in my `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment`? Something like `\if@lastlineofpage` or something like that...

Of course, I tried the famous

```
\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000
```

and nothing changed. I think the instructions to get rid of my problem should be written inside the `\newcommand...`

Thanks for your help.

Here's the heading of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside=yes]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancybox}
```

Comment: Why don't use *theorems like* environment from `amsthm`? You can format it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should use `\addvspace` instead of `\vspace` in these cases; for not breaking after the title, use ``\\*``

Comment: @Patou: See my edit please

Comment: Thanks to all. I missed the comments of Sigur and egreg because they are smaller.

I'm getting a better comprehension on the way this forum works :)

Comment: @Patou355: Could you give some feedback for my solution, please?

Comment: @Patou355: Please consider to accept my solution.

Answer (score 7):

The orphane titles can be prevented using box like environments, which allow more design as well and automated counting (something like theorems, as Sigur proposed)

I applied one of my favourite packages -- `tcolorbox` (No, I am not the author of that package, unfortunately :-()

The colours, frames can be changed at will, as optional argument to the environments. **Don't** use the `breakable` specifier either in the option list of the environments, as this could again leave orphane titles etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside=yes]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancybox}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{enigme}[1][]{title={\bfseries Énigme~\thetcbcounter:},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,#1}

\newtcolorbox{path}[1][]{title={\bfseries Parcours:},coltitle=DarkBlue,colbacktitle=yellow,#1}

\newcommand{\culture}[1]{\emph{#1.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enigme}
Aujourd'hui nous cherchons les chiens ;-)
\end{enigme}

\begin{path}
Nous allons 
\end{path}

\culture{Mais oui}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Now with spacings above and below the boxes, as well with no frames, to show the usage of the optional argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside=yes]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancybox}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{enigme}[1][]{enhanced,title={\bfseries Énigme~\thetcbcounter:},before skip=0.5cm,after skip=0.5cm,colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,#1}

\newtcolorbox{path}[1][]{enhanced,title={\bfseries Parcours:},coltitle=DarkBlue,colbacktitle=yellow,before skip=1.5cm, after skip=2cm,#1}

\newcommand{\culture}[1]{\emph{#1.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enigme}
Aujourd'hui nous cherchons les chiens ;-)
\end{enigme}

\begin{path}
Nous allons 
\end{path}

\culture{Mais oui}

\begin{enigme}[colback=green,breakable]
Aujourd'hui nous cherchons les chats ;-)
\end{enigme}

\begin{path}[colback=white,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,frame hidden]
Avant la maison
\end{path}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Next edit**

According to the OP's request to have a counter of its own and to let it start from zero, use

```
\newcounter{enigme}

\setcounter{enigme}{-1}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=enigme]{enigme}[1][]{enhanced,title={\bfseries Énigme~\thetcbcounter:},before skip=0.5cm,after skip=0.5cm,colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,#1}
```

instead of

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{enigme}[1][]{enhanced,title={\bfseries Énigme~\thetcbcounter:},before skip=0.5cm,after skip=0.5cm,colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,#1}
```

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of French language  has suffered in the last years